# How to add a select custom field to checkout page in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm adding extra fields to the checkout page in WooCommerce, 
I've added basic text fields ok, but I want a dropdown or select box with a few options, 
Here is what I've done so far but I've made an error somewhere

```
$fields['billing']['billing_meat'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Food options', 'woocommerce'),
'placeholder'   => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
'required'  => false,
'clear'     => false
'type'  => 'select',

'options' => array(                     // array of key => value pairs for select options
            __('I eat meat', 'woocommerce') => __('I eat mate', 'woocommerce'),
            __('meat is gross', 'woocommerce') => __('meat is gross', 'woocommerce'),
```

Maybe I'm not defining 'type' field correctly?

thanks loads

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If that is your exact code, then the problem is that you are missing a comma after `'clear' => false`.

I've tested this and it works:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_meat'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Food options', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => false,
    'clear'       => false,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'options'     => array(
        'eat-meat' => __('I eat maet', 'woocommerce' ),
        'not-meat' => __('Meat is gross', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    );
```

Note that I also did not use `__()` on the options array keys. It's better to not translate those.

Answer (score 7):

this is working. here's my code

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'dropdown' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function dropdown( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['dropdown'] = array(
        'label'     => __('dropdown', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('dropdown', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'type'      => 'select',
     'options'     => array(
        'option 1' => __('option 1', 'woocommerce' ),
        'option 2' => __('option 2', 'woocommerce' )
        )//end of options
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

this works. but it seems that the value is not being saved under _billing_dropdown. I used "admin columns" plugin to add a field in the order table (admin side). under my custom field "dropdown", no value shows up. where can i retrieve the value? same goes with my other custom field "purpose" that is under "_billing_purpose" and is type=>'textarea'. thanks!

here's a screenshot
https://scontent-b-hkg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10696182_985415141473105_5302358697439449940_n.jpg?oh=74cb5ebc6b1ad6dd0c29e51293b61fdf&oe=5502613C

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but since you didn't seem to get the answer you were looking for, you need to update the order meta with the field value. Here's how to do that:

    /**
    * Update the order meta with field value
    */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'dropdown_update_order_meta' );
  
    function dropdown_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['dropdown'] ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $order_id, 'How You Found Us', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['dropdown'] ) );
         }
    }